# Dynamic DNS checking site?

Tags: dns, website, web, isp

Basically, I use to have a site bookmarked that would create a unique subdomain and forward you there, then, when you do a DNS lookup on that subdomain it would mark the DNS IP down and give it to you when you load the webpage. Does anyone know any sites like that? I really need one now to test my DNS address (I swear to god my ISP is hijacking my DNS request from google's DNS).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about such redirect pages that send you to search results rather than returning a DNS error?

If so, you could simply try to request a domain that's not existing and see whether you're redirected?

Or are we talking about hijacking used to redirect requests through some proxy, e.g. to recompress or filter content?

For the latter, you can try the following:

- Open a terminal window or command prompt (depending on your operating system).
- Ping the domain you think is redirected, e.g. `ping www.google.com`.
- Write down the IP that is shown.

From here on, you've got multiple possibilities. You can try one after the other or skip the first one as well:

**Compare returned IP adresses**

- Go to http://web-sniffer.net and input the domain as a standard address (the domain doesn't have to run a http server at all; it just has to be reachable from the internet; without a server running this might take quite a bit). In my example it would be `http://www.google.com/`.
- Select the request type `HEAD` (you don't need any document content etc.).
- Submit and check the results. Under "HTTP Request Header" the first line should be telling you the IP.
- Compare this IP with the one you've written down earlier. If they're completely different, it's possible your ISP spoofs the DNS request, but it's also possible that the difference is perfectly legit (e.g. due to the target domain being served by multiple different IPs/hosts).

**Determine the location/owner behind an IP**

- Use the IP you've written down first (using the `ping` command) and use a service such as http://www.ip2location.com/ to determine the domain name and possibly owner. If these doesn't fit the actual company you expected (e.g. the IP belongs to your ISP rather than a foreign company), it's quite likely something is being weird.

Comment: No, what I mean is basically the site follows these rules:-
A. Site has a home page (Site.com)
B. Site (Upon loading the homepage) generates a completely random and unique subdomain, say foobar.site.com
C. Site then listens for any DNS lookup requests coming in on said subdomain
D. Once a DNS lookup comes in, it makes a note and waits for the HTTP request to come in
E. Once the HTTP request comes in, it gives you the DNS server that requested the DNS lookup on said subdomain

Comment: Ah, so you want to determine which server asked your DNS for the domain name, because you think your ISP answers the requests despite them being aimed at Google's DNS? I don't think that's possible or really telling anything, due to the way the DNS system works.

Comment: It is possible as I use to host this exact system, although, due to financial reasons I no longer have a remote server to run said **very** basic script on. I use to also know a site that did it (Run by someone else), I just can't remember it.